# How to retain a specific word in a string throughout the column and remove all the rest?

Tags: r, stringr

My dataframe is this:

```
data <- data.frame(column = c("word1 word2 word3", "word2 word1", "word3 word2", "word1 word2", "word3", "word1 word2"))
data

  column
1 word1 word2 word3
2 word2 word1
3 word3 word2
4 word1 word2
5 word3
6 word1 word2
```

I want to retain the part "word1" in all rows where it occurs and remove the other parts of those strings.

My preferred output is this:

```
  column
1 word1
2 word1
3 word3 word2
4 word1
5 word3
6 word1
```

I tried `data$column %>% str_replace("^[word1]*", " ")`, but that didn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% mutate(column = str_replace(column, "^.*word1.*$", "word1"))
       column
1       word1
2       word1
3 word3 word2
4       word1
5       word3
6       word1
```

or with a capture group

```
data %>% mutate(column = str_replace(column, "^.*(word1).*$", "\\1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that checks if `word1` is in the column and then replaces the rest if it is.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data_frame(column = c("word1 word2 word3", "word2 word1", "word3 word2", "word1 word2", "word3", "word1 word2"))

data %>% mutate(column = if_else(grepl("word1", column), "word1", column))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   column     
#>   <chr>      
#> 1 word1      
#> 2 word1      
#> 3 word3 word2
#> 4 word1      
#> 5 word3      
#> 6 word1
```

Created on 2018-08-25 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).